# How to use git ? when you are not smart enough

Tags: git

I tried to use it for one year or more.
Still having problems. Still do not know how to get help. Is searching the internet is the only way?
How to remember all those command line options? Most of them are inconsistent and untranslatable into a normal language

For example, this time I need to do a "rebase" (or may be, not, because I have a conflict in one file (bitbcuket shows me), I am trying to do a "rebase", then I don't know how to merge, then it shows me some warnings, I am trying to "rebase --abort", then I need to know the branch name. How to list branch names from the command line?
How to force the rebase? Because I do not understand all those "merge tools", they look broken. Is there a change just to force rebase and do file changes manually?

How to KNOW that `git branch -r` shows the list of branches?

How to KNOW how to exit from `git branch -r`?

Please do not recommend to use Some Tool. I am tired of jumping between the tools. What if that tool is not available at another computer/VM/...?
It seems, if a "git" tool is integrated into you IDE, then it has a different vocabulary and it doesn't provide some features or buggy.
And this was my mistake trying to learn how to use them. Instead, I should try to understand how to use the console.

P.S.
Did someone try to translate "checkout" in Google Translate or in Google Image Search into your language? The output doesn't make sense at all. 
Should I live in US to understand git?

Update:
Do I need to hire some git teacher? Is there any possibility?

P.S.2
why "git add" does update? How should I know, that when I need to add all modified tracked files to index I should search in Google "update index", not "add to index"?

P.S.3.
Probably, I should create a wiki page for myself somewhere (btw, where?) with list of most useful git commands and to translate my language into git commands.

Comment: I think "Pro Git" is the best book on Git, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2. It's been helping me understand how Git works.

Comment: I'd start with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4 and then move to http://think-like-a-git.net/ --- Also, https://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/, https://learngitbranching.js.org/, etc

Comment: _"untranslatable into a normal language"_ - yeah. Sorry, English definitely is not normal

Answer (score 2):

1. Read/do some basic git course/tutorial/book/guide. Don't just start using git without any training and expect that you will figure it out along the way. You'll first want to be familiar to the basic information model of git. Some fundamentals you should try to make sure you are familiar with:

   - What is a blob/tree/commit/tag and how do they relate to each other?
   - What is the difference between the work tree, the index (or staging area) and committed changes?
   - What is a branch? (there are many misconceptions about branches, as branches are a bit different than in some other version control systems)
   - What is a remote?
   - What is the difference between a local branch and a remote branch?
2. Print a git cheat sheet and keep next to your computer. There are many available online. Just google [git cheat sheet](https://www.google.com/search?q=git%20cheat%20sheet). This will be a quick reference. Being able to easily glance at it while you are unsure about a command will provide you with repetition which is good for learning.
3. Don't aspire to know all arguments/flags to different git commands by heart. 
    Knowing `git <command> --help` is usually enough! After a few times of checking the help page, you will start to learn the options that you need to use most frequently. Other, less frequent options, you can look up in the help page when you need them.

   - Do you want to know what `git branch -r` option does? Then do`git branch --help` and search for `-r`.
   - Do you want to know how to list remote branches? Then do `git branch --help` and search for `remote`.
4. Browse the [most upvoted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=50) with the `git` tag here on stack overflow. Git is not very easy the first time you use it, but you're not alone. Reading through some of the most upvoted questions will make you aware of what difficulties/misunderstandings/mistakes other users have experienced, and provide you with the opportunity to learn from them.

Comment: I'd also recommend to them to learn some command line basics. See _"How to KNOW how to exit"_

Comment: @evolutionxbox I didn't really understand that part. What does it mean to exit from `git branch -r`? I considered at first that `git branch` output might be using the configured `core.pager`, and the solution would be to configure `cat` as the pager. But it seems this is not the case. Even if I configure `less` as my pager, `git branch` command returns immediately after printing.

Comment: Maybe they’re using a different setup? Or windows?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of paths you can follow.

1. You can start with bare command line commands, I know I know you said that you don't remember them. Please consider [this](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) guide as a reference. It is friendly and simple, it includes all the necessary commands you need.
2. If command line tools are not meant for you there's no problem, give a try to some graphical utility, [Kraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) is out there for you. I think this is the best graphical git software you can find, it is well integrated so you can log in with your account and perform basic and advanced stuff from there pretty easily, plus you have a clear representation of your project's history.

In my personal experience, I started by using the command line tools pretty extensively for git, recently I switched to Kraken because my projects are getting bigger and I love looking at the timeline.

That said, learning a new tool requires a basic understanding of its working principles. You will need to understand committing, branching, remotes, stashing, merging and rebasing from a theoretical point of view before using any tool (bash or GUI).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

It is a complex tool with a ton of options.
To learn it, I would recommend immerse yourself in it.

1. Print this [Git cheat sheet](https://about.gitlab.com/images/press/git-cheat-sheet.pdf) and place it on your desk. So you can refer to it if you get stuck.
2. Slowly go through [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/lab_01.html), it teaches you how to use `git` on your own pc without installing additional tools. And it is pretty short.

After this, you will have a pretty stable foundation. So you will be able to search for specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. At the earlier stage, you can use some git **GUI tools** like [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com).
2. After you understand what git does when you pull, merge, push, commit etc, you can start **trying with very basic commands** like status, add, commit and do rest of the complex things with tower, coz', of course, *when you view what is changing after every git command*, you'll get more confident in it. Or, with command, you can run `git status` or check into tower what has changed everytime after executing this command.
3. Rest of the tutorial links or learning materials or guides or cheatsheet references, you can find in other Answers

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem a few years ago. I used [`hub`](https://github.com/github/hub), a command-line wrapper for Git which makes Git easier to use with GitHub. It has a similar interface to the normal  Git so when you're ready to move on from [`hub`](https://github.com/github/hub), it will be an easy switch.

**Edit**
Another alternative is using a GUI like [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/git-client), it can list all the branches and more!

Comment: I myself found it very useful to learn git from the command line as it makes me understand what's actually happening, as opposed to GUIs where it just "does the magic".

Comment: @ikkentim I started with a GUI because it was easier, but over time I needed to get things done faster so I learned the Git command-line. But the GUI gave me a grasp of what was happening so learning the Git command-line was easier to understand that it would have been without the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [Altassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git) tutorial quite helpful. Have a look through it.